# How is this solenoid going to last for months?

Tags: battery-operated, solenoid, solenoid-valve

After buying a water control unit for my garden I got curious of how it worked, so I picked it apart and had a look before assembling it again :-). It uses 2x1.5V AA Alkaline batteries to output 3V (guessing, as that is the minimum for a lot of micro controllers).

I'm no electrical engineer, just curious :-).

What I've learned is that it controls a valve with a solenoid. Then I got even more curious since I've been dabbling with micro controllers and cheap parts from China.

My question is how are the battery lasting? I bought it to water my grass (it was sold as a general purpose watering device). I water the garden every 2./3. day for ~30 minutes. I've read many of these electrical magnetic fields sucks current and would drain the battery flat in less then a week in my case.

I found this 3v solenoid on [Mouser](https://no.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Delta-Electronics/DSOS-0416-03D?qs=7MVldsJ5UazBinVxAFhTjg%3D%3D) and it's [datasheet](https://no.mouser.com/datasheet/2/632/delta_electronics_06152020_DSOS-0416-1860099.pdf) states it uses 1.28A while in the active state (normally closed/open). I guess the active state would be letting the water thru as that's the least active time. It's not the same as the one I have in my watering device, but I guess there is no black magic going on here and the speccs is about the same.

Typical mAh of the battery is 2850 mAh ([PDF](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1512013.pdf)) and I have two batteries in series (guessing).

So the batteries is going to last me ~2 hours of watering?

Any toughs from an electrical engineer?

Comment: what happens if you turn on the water and remove the batteries? ... does the water remain flowing?

Comment: presenting data about some random solenoid on Mouser is useless, because that is not the solenoid you are asking about

Comment: I used a digital AC timer and an AC washing machine surplus solenoid valve, normally closed.

Comment: Why just do not share the results of real test? My guess Mattman right. Oversize it is a cheap Chinese fake.

Answer (score 2):

It probably uses a Bistable Latching Solenoid Valve. These only require pulses of current to change state. Something like this:

https://www.hydralectric.com/products/solenoid-valves/latching-bi-stable-solenoid-valves/